# AngularJS cookie data being returned as undefined after page refresh

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I am using AngularJS for a web development project and I'm stuck because I am trying to store the user session in a cookie so that it's impossible for them to access login or registration page when they are already logged in, and also for various other reasons.

What seems to be happening is that I am storing user data into a cookie, and i used console.log() to return the data stored in the cookie and the storing process seems to be working. However, when I attempt to access the login screen, I am still able to do so.

So for debugging purposes I added another console.log() to check the data stored in the cookie when the login page is accesed and it returns as undefined.

Does anyone know what's the issue in my code that is causing the data to be dumped?

```
  function login(email, password, callback) {
        return $http.post('/api/v1/auth/login/', {
                email: email,
                password: password
            }).then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                Authentication.setAuthenticatedAccount(data.data);
                window.location = '/:username';
            }, function (response) {
                var response;
                response = { success: false, message: 'Username or password is incorrect' };
                callback(response);
                console.error('Epic failure!');
            });
 /**
 * @name getAuthenticatedAccount
 * @desc Return the currently authenticated account
 * @returns {object|undefined} Account if authenticated, else `undefined`
 * @memberOf hrlite.authentication.services.Authentication
 */

function getAuthenticatedAccount() {
    if (!$cookies.authenticatedAccount){
        return;
    }

    return $cookies.getObject('authenticatedAccount');
}
/**
 * @name isAuthenticated
 * @desc Check if the current user is authenticated
 * @returns {boolean} True is user is authenticated, else false.
 * @memberOf hrlite.authentication.services.Authentication
 */
function isAuthenticated() {
    console.log("account:" + getAuthenticatedAccount());

    return !!$cookies.authenticatedAccount;
}

 /**
 * @name setAuthenticatedAccount
 * @desc Stringify the account object and store it in a cookie
 * @param {Object} user The account object to be stored
 * @returns {undefined}
 * @memberOf hrlite.authentication.services.Authentication
 */

function setAuthenticatedAccount(account) {

    $cookies.putObject('authenticatedAccount', account);
}
```

Comment: what version of angular? Aren't you supposed to use a `get()` method in current versions? Not sure what `$cookies.authenticatedAccount` is supposed to do and `return` by itself will return undefined when you call the function

Comment: good point.. I guess the confusion comes from following different tutorials that are using different versions of angular. I'll do some research on the current version of cookies and I'll update my code accordingly, and get back to you if there are still problem. Thanks

Comment: I think all you need to do is return `return $cookies.getObject('authenticatedAccount'); || false`

Comment: yep you're right! it's because i wasn't using getters! thanks so much!